# What's the problem in logic in defining satisfaction in terms of a formal translation (and thus obtain the rules as theorems)?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Enderton's  *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic*,  p. 83, gives an informal definition of satisfaction (I paraphrase):

> $\vDash_{\cal A} \phi[s]$ iff the translation of $\phi$ determined by the structure ${\cal A}$ and the assignment $s$ is true.

Next, Enderton gives the formal definition based on satisfaction rules. Am I correct to say that these satisfaction rules can be obtained as theorems from the informal definition, after the translation of a formula is defined?  The idea for the definition of the translation is simply to recursively translate the sub-expressions and recombine them as in the overall expression.

Let $\phi^{{\cal A},s}$ denote the translation of $\phi$ given ${\cal A}$ and $s$. It seems that the satisfaction rules are theorems of the informal definition of satisfaction assuming the above recursive definition of $\phi^{{\cal A},s}$. For example, consider the rule  $\vDash_{\cal A} \neg \phi[s]$ iff $\neg (\vDash_{\cal A} \phi[s])$.  If we apply the informal definition, this becomes $(\neg \phi)^{{\cal A},s}$ iff $\neg (\phi^{{\cal A},s})$, which can clearly be proven given the definition of translation.

Note added: An answer below says that a motivation to avoid a translation function is when we need to make a link with a language that is informal and thus could not be the target of the translation. This raises the question at another level.  In which way less formalization of the semantic can help make the link with an informal language? To put it in another way, how would we know that the semantic matches with this informal natural language? One could argue that, on the contrary, more formalization, thus a formalization of the semantic, could only help to explain a connection. Though, of course, given that the natural language is informal, we will never have a rigorous description of the connection.

Comment: The problem is: what language are you translating to? Before you can define the translation operation, you need to define the target language, and then you'll still have the problem of defining satisfaction for *that* language. The mathematical framework we're using to study logic (the "metalanguage") can't formally "see itself".

Comment: In other words, there's no preexisting formal notion of a mathematical sentence or the truth of a sentence. That's exactly what we're establishing when we define satisfaction.

Comment: I find it strange that the question is down voted. I expected a bit that it could be, because some would think that the answer is obvious, but when I see Karl's comment, I don't think it's entirely obvious. Please anyone, compensate for these down votes.  It's a useful question.

Comment: In fact, with the comments and the down votes, I don't know what is the answer. Is it that it's incorrect to define a translation function? Is it that it's entirely obvious that  a translation function is being defined?  Let say there is a problem with the definition of a translation function, there must be an explanation for that. Down votes are not informative here. This question is a good occasion to say something intelligent and useful.

Comment: Karl, in some proofs, we do consider the truth of statements in the mathematical universe in which the formal language is interpreted. For example,  I am looking at a proof  of the incompleteness of second order logic and the proof considers whether or not GCH hold in this mathematical universe.

Answer (score 2):

The formal definition of "$\models_{\mathcal{A}} \varphi[s]$" based on satisfaction rules *is* the definition of the "translation of $\phi$ determined by $\mathcal{A}$ and $s$".

If you're not convinced, I suggest you write out in detail the recursive definition of "translation" that you have in mind. You'll find it's exactly the same as the recursive definition of $\models$, just using different notation.

---

Let me try to clarify my answer in response to the comments below. I'm making two claims here:

(1) When Enderton writes informally about a "translation", he's referring to the definition of satisfaction (which "translates" each logical connective to its meta-language counterpart) and nothing more.

(2) If you carefully write out the formalization of "translation" you have in mind, you'll find that it differs from the definition of satisfaction only in notational choices.

Now in the comments, you wrote that what I said is false because "it forgets that the right hand side can be seen as the construction of an expression". Here I'll reiterate Karl's point from the comments. If this "expression" is a formula in the meta-language, then it is not itself a mathematical object, so theres no way formalize the idea of "constructing" it. All we can do is give a meta-language definition like the recursive definition of satisfaction. On the other hand, if your "expression" is not a formula in the meta-language, then it is a formula of some object language, and you've just pushed off the problem to defining satisfaction for *that* language.

Comment: I imagine the asker wants to split the definition of satisfaction into a "translation" step (defining a function from sentences to meta-sentences) followed by a "truth" step (some kind of explicit self-evaluation in the metalanguage).

Comment: @Karl Sure, but I think my point stands: the definition of $\models$ *is* a function from sentences to meta-sentences.

Comment: Agreed, in an informal sense of "is a function". Does it make sense to try to define it as a "real" mathematical object? Per my comments on the question, I don't think this would be useful, but I wonder if there's a perspective I'm missing.

Comment: Alex, strictly speaking what you say is false  because "iff" only means that the truth value are equal: it forgets that the right hand side can be seen as a construction of an  expression. You should adjust your answer to that. Moreover, I did what you suggested even before asking the question.   However, i did that only after I asked the question to myself and the question did not come easily. When it came, I naturally  wondered why it's not said explicitly. Also,  the notation does not suggest a translation function. This is why, even though I saw it,   I asked the question.

Comment: @Dominic108 I've edited in response to your comment.

Comment: @Karl After seeing Dominic108's comment, I now agree with your interpretation of the question. I also agree that there's no way to make the "translation" into a "real" function. I've edited my answer to try to clarify.

Comment: This is good. Indeed, a translation function  would be less general. It would not cover the case where the object language is the only one with formal rules. It's important  that we can define satisfaction without such a translation function. However,  it does not mean that it's not a useful perspective. I disagree  with  "we just pushed off the problem to defining satisfaction for that language", because it suggests that it cannot be useful. Perhaps, you could be more positive in your answer.  Consider that, if you cannot imagine a useful purpose, it may only be a lack of imagination.

Comment: Moreover, it's a mistake to identify the language for the semantical structures with the language where we do the usual mathematics.  The semantical structures are some kind of mathematical objects.  In intuitionist logic, we use other kind of semantical structures. So, we can view the semantical structures as mathematical objects without creating an infinite regress. The semantical structures and the formal language can be seen as two formal parts that together define a logic, separated from the natural language of mathematics.